# How can I prepend leading ZEROS on ZIP codes when there are only 3 and 4 digits using LODASH or Typescript?

Tags: json, typescript, lodash, angular13

so, I have the USPS entire CITY, STATE, COUNTY, LAT LON, and ZIP CODE as seen below in the example from said JSON.  It's 349,000+ lines long. Very cool.

```
...

  {
    "zip_code": 988,
    "latitude": 18.393355,
    "longitude": -65.972495,
    "city": "Carolina",
    "state": "PR",
    "county": "Carolina"
  },
  {
    "zip_code": 1001,
    "latitude": 42.140549,
    "longitude": -72.788661,
    "city": "Agawam",
    "state": "MA",
    "county": "Hampden"
  },
...
```

As you can see, the upper Zip Code has only three digits and the next one, in order has 4 then later down the line there are finally 5 digits.

What I need to do is LOOP through all Zip Codes that === 3 && === 4 and add TWO ZEROS for those Zips with 3 digits and ONE ZERO for Zips with 4 digits.

This NEEDS to be on the fly or need to do a GLOBAL search and replace, ONE TIME, so the add'l Zeros are already there. This comes from the USPS without the leading zeros.

citystatezip is imported like so

```
import * as citystatezip from 'src/assets/json/city-state-zip-county.json';
```

Here's what I've tried... or am trying:

```
  /**
   * @name getAllZips
   * @description gets all the Zips
   * @returns OBJECT Any
   */
  getAllZipCodes(): any {
    let zips = [];
    zips = _.map(citystatezip as unknown as any, 'zip_code');
    let result = _.find(zips, function (n) {
      if (n === 3) {
????????????????
      } else if (n === 4) {
????????????????
      }
    }, 0)
    return result;
  }
```

**UPDATE:**
Added this as a solution from @Kelly

```
  getAllZipCodes(): any {
    let zips = [];
    zips = _.map(citystatezip as unknown as any, 'zip_code');
    let result = _.find(zips, function (n) {
         n.toString().padStart(5, "0")
    }, 0)
    return result;
  }
```

The problem, not with @Kellys solution, is it's not going into the "IF" statement.

Remember, there are 43,625 cities, which is 349000/8 which is the {} and the 6 lines in each.  Am I not doing the _.find correctly?

**UPDATE 2:**

```
  /**
   * @description set and gets all zip codes
   * @argument nothing
   * @returns zipcodes for get
   */
  public setZipCodes(): void {
    this.zipcodes = this.getAllZipCodes();
  }

  public getZipCodes(): Object {
    return this.zipcodes;
  }

  /**
   * @name getAllZips
   * @description gets all the Zips
   * @returns OBJECT Any
   */
  getAllZipCodes(): any {
    let zips = [];
    zips = _.map(citystatezip as unknown as any, 'zip_code');
    let result = _.find(zips, function (n) {
      return n.toString().padStart(5, "0") <<< like so???
    }, 0)
    this.zipcodes = result;
    return result;
  }
```

and in the COMPONENT calling the SERVICE above, here's the code in ngOnInit()

```
    this.allCities = this.elementService.getCities();
    this.allStates = this.elementService.getStates();
    this.allZipcodes = this.vaForm21elementService.getZipCodes();
    console.log("All cities: ", this.allCities);
    console.log("All states: ", this.allStates.default);
    console.log("All zip codes: ", this.allZipcodes);
```

Comment: You need to convert them to strings or else the leading zeroes will mean nothing. You can do that with `n.toString().padStart(5, "0")`.

Comment: See UPDATE where I added your solution...

Comment: Where have you added my solution...?

Comment: Just did and fixed the single = with ===. D'oh!

Comment: OH, WAIT! Do I not need the IF STATEMENT?

Comment: Well... `n` can't be 3 and 4 at the same time (you need to check the length of `n` vs 3 or 4, not `n` itself)... And with my solution you don't need to check the length of `n`...

Comment: AH HA! fixing my code now and testing.

Comment: Remove the IF STATEMENT and I'm getting this in the CONSOLE All zip codes:  undefined

Comment: I think you're missing a `return`.

Comment: See entire method structure,... in UPDATE 2 - give it a couple min to load

Comment: Missing a return in the `find` callback

Comment: OK, last comment, I have a result with the return, a SINGLE zip code; 501, but I need to add those zeros and loop through into a NEW ARRAY. I think I can make it from here unless you want to make one more suggestion as a SOLUTION I'll accept

Comment: Well I'm assuming `_.find` is lodash? So then that `find` call doesn't make sense. You don't even need lodash's array utilities. You can use the built-in `map`: `zips.map((n) => n.toString().padStart(5, "0"));` (replaces `_.find`)

Comment: BOOYAH!!!!!!!! Add my code as a solution like so, and I'll vote for you! THANK YOU! All 42,741 zips in a single array! YOU ROCK!    getAllZipCodes(): any {
    let zips = [];
    zips = _.map(citystatezip as unknown as any, 'zip_code');
    let result = zips.map((n) => n.toString().padStart(5, "0"));
    return result;
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `_.find` with `map`:

```
let result = zips.map((n) => n.toString().padStart(5, "0"));
```

`padStart` pads the start of the string:

```
988   => 00988
1001  => 01001
31553 => 31553
```

[padStart reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)